# Using orderby with 2 meta keys

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, order

I can use `orderby` with one meta key in the `WP_Query` using following:

```
'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
'meta_key'  => 'my_key_1',
```

However is it possible to use orderby based on the calculation of 2 meta fields?

For example I have two meta fields `my_key_1` and `my_key_2`. I want to divide the value key 1 by 2 and orderby that result. Something like

```
meta_key = my_key_1/my_key_2
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be to sort at a database level by a dynamically calculated column. This is too complex for me.

Having your task on production I would probably create a third meta key: 'division' derivated from the two and update its value on every post save. Then I would sort by this key in WP_Query().

Third option for small amount of posts would be to sort an array.

Define helper fuction:

```
function sort_by_division( $posts ) {
  foreach ( $posts as $i => $post ) :
    $my_key_1 = (float)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_key_1', true );
    $my_key_2 = (float)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_key_2', true ); 
    $division = $my_key_1 / $my_key_2;
    $divisions[$i] = $division;
  endforeach;
  array_multisort( $divisions, SORT_DESC, $posts );
  return $posts;
}
```

And apply it for the results of the query:

```
<?php $myposts = sort_by_division( get_posts() ); ?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
  $my_key_1 = (float)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_key_1', true );
  $my_key_2 = (float)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_key_2', true ); 
  $division = $my_key_1 / $my_key_2;
  ?>
  <li>
    <?php the_title(); ?><br>
    my_key_1: <?php echo $my_key_1; ?><br>
    my_key_2: <?php echo $my_key_2; ?><br>
    division: <?php echo $division; ?>
  </li>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
</ul>
```

As I said, not usable for large amount of posts because of memory consumption. An option with third meta key is most efficient.